# Implementing machine learning on android

Tags: machine-learning

I want to implement machine learning on android for human activity recognition. Which tool works the best for implementing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad to answer without learning specific task you are trying to perform, but in general - use tensorflow. It could successfully run on Android out of the box and has tons of algorithms available. You could start with this reading this post:
https://jalammar.github.io/Supercharging-android-apps-using-tensorflow/